# Concatenate set of objects, group by value in java

Tags: java, object, java-stream

I'm making a `Set` of **objects** that consists of `name` and `value`. My requirement is to create a new `Set` by grouping the `Set` based on objects that have the same `value` and `concate` the property `name` into a single `string` separated by `","`.

Example:

```
   Name: Test,     value: Random value
   Name: Test 2,   value: Some random value
   Name: Test 3,   value: Random value
```

I want the result to be a **Set** like this:

```
Name: Test, Test 3,  value: Random value
Name: Test 2 ,   value: Some random value
```

The **class** for understanding:

```
public class Test {
    private String name;
    private String value;
    }
```

How to create a new `Set` by grouping the `Set` based on `value` and *concatenate* the `name` into a `string` using [Java Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html)?

Comment: Use a loop to iterate the Set and extract the bits you need

Comment: Worded differently: you need to group by value?

Comment: always good to share what you have tried already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var result = setOfTests.stream()
    .collect(
        Collectors.collectingAndThen(
            Collectors.groupingBy(Test::getValue,
                // for each group, map each element to their name and join
                Collectors.mapping(Test::getName, Collectors.joining(", "))
            ), // at this point we have a Map<String, String> mapping from value to joined name
            // now we turn each entry in the map back to a Test object
            // "getValue" below refers to Map.Entry.getValue, not Test.getValue
            map -> map.entrySet().stream().map(x -> new Test(x.getValue(), x.getKey()))
                .collect(
                    Collectors.toList() // or toSet or whatever you like
                )
        )
    );
// result is a List<Test>
```

Note that the order of the joined names is undefined if your set is unordered, so it could be either "Test, Test 3," or "Test 3, Test,".

Comment: imho, a `toMap` with `megeFunction` would have been much simpler

Comment: @Naman I always forgot that exists. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: Thank you for your answear it did work! You just forgot to add the separator "," in your  `Collectors.joining(", ")`  (I tested the solution with groupedBy before the edit).

Comment: @FilipHuhta I thought the commas are included in the names of `Test` objects. If not, you can replace `String::concat` with `(x, y) -> x + ", " + y`.

Comment: @Sweeper Okey, I will try it!

Comment: @FilipHuhta Actually I think using `joining` could have the advantage of creating fewer intermediate strings, so although `toMap` is shorter, my first solution might be a little quicker.

Answer (score 6):

Using `toMap` with merging (additionally stream elements are before sorted by Name):

```
Set<Test> result = s.stream()
                    .sorted((t1,t2)-> t1.getName().compareTo(t2.getName())) 
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Test::getValue, 
                                              Function.identity(),
                                              (t1,t2)-> new Test(t1.getName()+","+t2.getName(),
                                                                 t1.getValue())))
                                       .values()
                                       .stream()
                                       .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
String testValues = tests.stream()
                .map(Test:: getValue)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

You can use the below sample and change the function in map to get either the values or the keys

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Test> tests = new HashSet<>();
        tests.add(new Test("First", "1st"));
        tests.add(new Test("Second", "2nd"));
        tests.add(new Test("Third", "3rd"));
        tests.add(new Test("Fourth", "4th"));
        System.out.println(tests);
        String testValues = tests.stream()
                .map(Test:: getValue)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
        System.out.println(testValues);

    }
```

You can modify your test class as below

```
    public class Test {
        public Test(String name, String value) {
            this.name = name;
            this.value = value;
        }

        private String name;
        private String value;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Test{");
            sb.append("name='").append(name).append('\'');
            sb.append(", value='").append(value).append('\'');
            sb.append('}');
            return sb.toString();
        }
    }
```

Important : This doesn't guarantee the the same order of insertion